# k-fold cross validation of segmented regression

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation, linear-model, segmented-regression

I am solving a MILP problem in my current master thesis and I got stuck with some issue. Originally, I had it a set of data points that I was using to build an OLS regression model of second order.

Because of technical reasons I need to implement the piece wise linear regression of this data set. At the begining my idea was to fit a normal regression model as:

$f=a_{0i}+\sum_{j=1}^L a_{ji}x_{ti}^j + r_i$

And later convert the polynomial outputted into its linear form as follows

$\hat{f}(x) = y^k + (\frac{y^k-y^{k-1}}{b^k-b^{k-1}}), \ x \in [b^k,b^{k-1}], \ \forall k=1,\cdots ,d \ being \ d \ number \ of  \ breakpoints$

The problem is that with this approach I would lose some information (because at the end I am fitting a new regression to something that is already a fitting).

After I notice this issue I decided to use the segmented R package to build my PWL model. However, If I want to implement a k-fold cross validation I need to define the break points before (if not, some of the randomly selected points in the fold could be from different part of the curves achieving a disastrous fitting).

Of course I can "estimate" what are the right break points and create the folds in each segment. But I do not know how good is this approach.

Has anyone implemented something similar before?